# Detect if multiple SVG paths are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, svg, raphael

Can anyone help me with this... basically, I need to detect if any SVG path (from Raphael JS) in an array is clicked, something like this:

```
var myArray = [path_ur,path_us,path_ut];

myArray.bind('click',function() {
     alert('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have jQuery, use it.

```
$.each(myArray, function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
     alert('clicked');
    })
});
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you! Arrays are a weakness of mine, I must fix that :)